# MySQL find lowest price of multiple products in multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have a database called Pricelist.  In it there are several tables eg. Store1, store2, etc.  Each has a list of the products.  Most products exist in each store but some only exits in one or two stores.  I want to have something that I can run within SQL (stored procedure?) That will find the lowest price of a product by checking the price from each store and then when it finds the lowest price, it will get that price, along with the UPC,Description, and other columns and put all that information in a final table called BestPrices.  Then it do it all again for each product in every store.  So when it's done.  every product from all the stores should be listed once in the BestPrices table with the lowest price and the additional information from the other columns I chose.  Is this possible?  I know it's a lot.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to add to this.  I have a 3 tables.  Each has descr., price, quantity.  Each table has the same products but different stores.  I want to locate which store has the lowest price for each product and then copy the descr., price, & quantity from that store to a 4th table.  Is there anyone who can provide me code for that?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can create temporary/buffer table to collect data from tables store, then you can query from that table to get the lowest price.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is display the best prices, then an `SQL View` should do the trick. A `View` is enough to

> find the lowest price of a product by checking the price from each
>   store ... along with other columns and ... do it all again for each
>   product in every store.

However, an SQL View is rendered at runtime and hence, you do not have the values stored in a table, per se. That is, the best prices are calculated as and when you invoke the view

If you want to have the values stored for future viewing, then you shall need a `Stored Procedure` which shall insert the values into a physical table.

In the case of using a procedure, you should take care as to what should happen to the existing data when you insert into the table.

Also, your post doesn't include details regarding the actual table structure or the common identifier for the product across all the tables. Those details can greatly influence the design and performance of the View/Procedure.

Comment: I'm still new to this but the second part sounds exactly like what I am looking for.  I want to keep the existing data in tact where it is.  The common identifier will be the prodUPC column.  That's the name of the column in each table.  Every table has the same columns and once I figure out which store has the lowest price from that ProdUPC, I want to copy all the info for that upc from that store to a separate table including the prodUPC, prodModel, prodDesc. etc.  Most every column is just a varchar(50) with the exception of the prodDesc Column which I believe is text.  Does that help?